# Почему не изменяется переменная?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему foo не изменяется? Что происходит при добавлении внутренней функции таким же именем?

Comment: Да ничего не происходит. Функция foo объявлена внутри bar() и соответственно является локальной для нее, она не становится глобальной. А переменная foo попадает в bar() через замыкание и поэтому внутри является сама собой

Comment: Кстати я не понял почему у вас foo "не изменяется" интересно в каком контексте вы это делаете. foo должна стать равна 10 и становится ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри функции `bar` есть локальная переменная `foo`, которая сначала (на `{` после `bar()`) указывает на функцию. Потом этой локальной переменной присвоено значение 10. Глобальная переменная `foo` остается без изменений.

```
<script>
var foo = 1;

function bar() {
  alert(foo.toString());
  foo = 10;
  alert(foo);
  return;

  function foo() {};
}

bar();
alert(foo);
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо за объяснение)

Comment: @Igor Только вот если этот пример выполнить в хроме, в консоли, то alert даст значение 10 ...

Comment: @Mike - not in my Chrome (nor in FF or IE)

Comment: @Igor Вы слово `var` не забыли снаружи ? одной строкой в консоли наберите: `var foo=5; function bar() {foo=10;} bar(); alert(foo);` И как бы 10 и должно получаться потому как выходит замыкание.

Comment: @Mike - Ключевой момент здесь - наличие объявления локальной функции `foo` внутри `bar`.